# Failing SSL connection on MAC

Tags: macos, ssl

I have met a VERY peculiar problem on my MAC recently. 
All SSL-connections fail. Well, browsers work fine, but for instance, curl and wget (and a bunch of other apps) fail.

```
curl -vk  https://s3.osl1.safedc.net
*   Trying 193.156.25.230...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to s3.osl1.safedc.net (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to s3.osl1.safedc.net:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to s3.osl1.safedc.net:443
```

I have even installed Openssl, but it fails the same way :

```
curl -vk  https://s3.osl1.safedc.net
*   Trying 193.156.25.230:443...
* Connected to s3.osl1.safedc.net (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem
  CApath: /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to s3.osl1.safedc.net:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to s3.osl1.safedc.net:443
```

The strangest, is that when I reinstall MacOS, it is fixed, until the next day ???!!!!

Can anybody think of what can be the problem here? I am out of options and pretty desperate.